# I'm unable to select the Id of the related record within the Flow. However, I can choose other fields without any issues

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, lookup, update

I have a weird problem and don't know how to solve it, maybe I am blind. Please have a look:

[image]

I need to update a lookup field on the Account object. This lookup field is present on the current record that is triggering the flow. The challenge I'm facing is that I'm unable to find a way to directly select the ID of the lookup. Instead of seeing the ID field, I can view all the other fields available for modification. However, I only require the ID for the update. I've attempted various syntax options, but none have yielded the desired outcome.

For example:

This syntax works fine:

```
{!$Record.Account__r.Main_Document__r.Owner:User}
```

But I need to select Main_Document__c ID instead.

This throws an error:

```
{!$Record.Account__r.Main_Document__c}
```

For me it looks like an SF bug, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Specify Conditions to identify records and set fields individually`

- This will prompt you to choose an Sobject Type (`Account`)
- Then the filter would be `Id = $Record.Account__c`
- And then you can set `Maintenance__c` to whatever